# Android - is there an equivalent of Objective-C language literals like @{@"key":@"value"}

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, data-structures, initialization

I'm jumping back into Android development and am interested [if there's a shorthand way of creating data structures, like arrays, dictionaries, etc.](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) If I remember correctly, primitives are auto boxed/unboxed in Java, but I'm not sure about more advanced data structures

In objective-c I can do

```
//NSNumber
@(1)
//dictionary
@{@"key":@"value"}
//array
@[one,two,three]
```

What is the Android/Java equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primitives are autoboxed like

```
Integer val = 1;
```

As for Arrays, you can create them inline

```
String[] array = {"one", "two", "three"}
```

But to pass an array to a method you need to use *new* explicitly

```
print(new String[] {"one", "two", "three"})
```

Unfortunately Java does not have any shorthand for inline HashMap (Dictionary) creation, but you can use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library

```
ImmutableMap.of("k1", "v1", "k2", "v2");
```

Answer (score 2):

1 could be interpreted as Number if needed like:

```
if (new Integer(1)==1)  //autoboxing/unboxing
...
```

there is no dictionary in Java, but it has Map like HashMap. But I don't know how to create map with one k/v pair that short. You have to create a new instace of a HashMap and then add one k/v like:

```
new HashMap<String,String>().put("key","value");
```

As for arrays:

```
new String []{"one","two","three"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are an example.

Integer number  = new Integer(1);
number.intValue();

HashMap mHashMap= new HashMap();
mHashMap.put("key","value");

ArrayList mArray = new ArrayList();
mArray.add("value1");